# Is there a fairly portable and succinct method for parsing an environment variable from a script?

Tags: perl, awk, sed, grep

I have come up with a few solutions, but I don't love them. I'm wondering if there's a better way.  I'm mainly looking for something that's succinct and doesn't require flags and is usable on most any unix system.  **I'm also not entirely sure which one of the below is most portable. As far as I know, the only one that's not is the `gawk` solution.**

---

**example file**

I want to parse the value of the `BAR` variable

```
# a comment
FOO="ENV_FOO"
BAR="ENV_BAR"
```

```
textfile="# a comment\nFOO=\"ENV_FOO\"\nBAR=\"ENV_BAR\""

# awk: split on "=" delimiter 
echo $textfile | awk -F "=" '/^BAR=/ { gsub(/"/,"",$2); print $2 }'

# awk: replace beginning of string with empty string; handle quotes with tr
echo $textfile | awk '/^BAR=/ { gsub(/^.*BAR=/, ""); print }' | tr -d '"'

# gawk: most straight-forward to me but not portable or DRY
echo $textfile | gawk '/^BAR=/ { print gensub(/^.*BAR="(.*)"$/, "\\1", "g") }'

# grep + sed
echo $textfile | grep ^BAR= | sed -E 's#^.*"(.*)"$#\1#'

# sed only
echo $textfile | sed -nE 's#^BAR="(.*)"$#\1#p'

# perl: maybe I just need to work on remembering these flags as this is succint
echo $textfile | perl -alE 'print $1 if /^BAR="(.*)"$/'
```

Each of them is straightforward in its own way but many require remembering special flags that need to be included in order to work. Is there another standard unix tool that handles this use-case I'm not thinking of?

Comment: The content of $textfile is not the same as the plain assignments above due to quoting. echo $textfile emits literal ```\``` ```n```, not linefeeds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
perl -wnE'/^BAR="([^"]+)/ and say $1' file
```

or

```
perl -wlne'/^BAR="([^"]+)/ and print $1' file
```

so to not enable *all* [feature](https://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html)s with [`-E`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches). The `-w` enables warnings, can probably drop it here.

---

As for "*remembering these flags*" the basics are very reasonable

- `-e` tells the interpreter to **E**valuate as code what comes between the quotes; this is what makes it a "one-liner," a *program* on the command line. It must come right before the program in quotes
- `-n` opens a file and feeds the program a line at a time, for all submitted files; this is what you want when working with files.  The `-p` does the same, *and* prints every (processed) line

That's that, for most common needs. So `perl -ne'...' file` runs code in `''` (along with effects of other switches) on every line of the file; I also *always* throw in `-w`.

There are quite a few other switches of course, described [in perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches), for more specific conveniences or uses.  A few prominent ones

- `-M` loads a module, as `-MModuleName`. Can also specify functions to import, see docs
- `-0777`reads the whole file at once ("slurp"). This sets the input record separator ([`$/`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-filehandles)) so that the whole file is seen as one "line" -- so we still also need `-n`.
- `-C` followed by number/list for Unicode features, for example `-CASD`
- `-l` used above, to handle **L**ine endings, strip them on input and append for output

Generally the line (file in slurp mode) goes into [`$_` variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables), the all-round default in Perl.

To see the code very close to what Perl runs for a given one-liner add `-MO=Deparse` to the switches, which uses [B::Deparse](https://perldoc.perl.org/B/Deparse.html) compiler backend (via [O](https://perldoc.perl.org/O.html) module)

Comment: So `perl -le 'print'` is essentially the same as `perl -e 'say'`? Thanks for the explanation this seems like a good option

Comment: That's a part of it, yes, plus: (1) need `-E` (capital) for `say` as that's a `feature` and is not loaded by default (2) with `-l` you get a `chomp` of input as well. There is no need for `chomp`-ing the line here as this regex can't match (and capture) the newline but it's prudent to do in general

Answer (score 3):

You can source the file:

```
source /path/to/the/textfile
echo "$BAR"
```

Comment: Note that `source` is only bash compliant and not available in POSIX sh shells

Comment: @Inian if source isn't available, the equivalent `.` is; https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot

Comment: Thanks but sourcing a file can have unintended effects such as setting environment variables you didn’t intend to.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `sed` version of the command that is guaranteed to be POSIX compliant as below

```
sed -n 's/^BAR="\([^"]*\).*$/\1/p' file
```

The `-n` and `p` flags are standard flags to instruct `sed` to print the captured pattern `\1` only if the regex is asserted as valid.

You can also use the regex you defined in the `gawk` variant in the OP as below.

```
sed -n 's/^BAR="\(.*\)"$/\1/p'
```

P.S. Note that there is no definitive answer for this unless you add more details on what sort of a minimal system (which might need POSIX only) you are running this on. Also you could profile each of the suggestions and choose the one that solves your use-case the best.

Comment: Yeah I understand this sounds like a “what’s your favorite way of doing x”, but what I was hoping for is either another portable shell utility that handles this use case or in the case of your reply pointing out my `sed` variant wasn’t portable. I don’t have a specific case in mind but there are often cases where I need to do this or something similar only to find out OSX or some Linux variant doesn’t have the latest gnu versions.

Answer (score 0):

**awk**

`echo $textfile | awk -F\" '/^BAR=/{print $2}'`

you can use the `"` as a field separator. 
This way the second awk value in the relevant line will return will be wanted variable value.

Answer (score 0):

This may be too cute by half, but you can convert the textfile into a perl program, converting the env assignments into hash assignments and appending a perl print statement for the result, using sed:

```
$ sed 's/\(.*\)=/$e{\1}=/;s/$/;/;$aprint $e{BAR}' textfile
# a comment;
$e{FOO}="ENV_FOO";
$e{BAR}="ENV_BAR";
print $e{BAR}
```

When you simply pipe that into perl, it gives you the result you want:

```
$ sed 's/\(.*\)=/$e{\1}=/;s/$/;/;$aprint $e{BAR}' textfile|perl
ENV_BAR
```

Besides too-cuteness, this of course has the additional burden of being somewhat inefficient -- two-pass rather than one- for the other solutions.

On the plus side, sed and perl are probably the **most** portable of the programs, and there are no "flags" whatsoever, so... trade-offs.

Update: It occurred to me that, because Environment Variables / syntax are designed for the shell anyway, the same idea could be used with the shell directly, albeit probably less "portably", without any syntax massaging. This is bash:

```
$ IFS=; echo -e "$(<textfile)\necho \$BAR"|bash -s
ENV_BAR
```

Explanation: Setting `IFS` to null stops the "Word Splitting" that otherwise removes newlines from the textfile output. The `-e` makes `echo` recognize the `\n` escape sequence. The textfile is processed via "Command Substitution". The `-s` to `bash` tells it to take standard input as its script.